# iOS Clang - C++ Code Minification

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang, llvm

I recently learned that on Android, you need to actively turn on C++ Minifaction to not have all symbols in your shipped code. (See **fvisibility** flag here: https://blog.algolia.com/android-ndk-how-to-reduce-libs-size/)

Our binary size was reduced by ~3 mb after doing this, which is awesome.

Is this on the Clang compiler, compiling for iOS enabled by default or do you need to do some specific setting for it in Xcode?

Comment: Command line option `-g0`.   Turns off generation of debugging information.   Setting up building for "Release" will generally also not generate such information.

Comment: Interesting...but on Android we also compiled for release and the info was still there - but maybe things are handled differently there. I'm not sure if I actually mean debugging information - the function names just had their actual names still - and after the minification only shorted names that are unreadable.